# Group policy setting to add administrator to folder redirection

Tags: group-policy

When you configure folder redirection on my documents in group policy and check the "Grant exclusive rights" check box, only the SYSTEM and user has rights to the folder. Domain administrators loose accesss.

I know how to manually add access back by changing the permissions/ownership but I'm sure I read about an additional group policy setting that modifies this mechanism so that administrators are also included when a workstation takes over exclusive control.

But I can't for the life of me find any details about what the policy is called/where it is. First time in a while that Google has let me down.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to grant exclusive rights? IMHO permissions should be configured on the file location and then let folder redirection JUST redirect.

Comment: That's what we have done in the past as part of our new user script. Best practise appears a little split here between letting the client machines do it themselves when the user first logs on or creating the folders with the right permissions when IT create the user

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to simply uncheck that option and to make sure that the Administrator has the appropriate permissions on the parent folder and that permissions inheritance is configured correctly.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288991

Comment: I will have to check this but I think this doesn't resolve the problem. That article describes how to configure the root folder for user's documents so that when the *user* creates their folder at first logon, it is able to do so, i.e. the permissions on the parent allow the user to create the folder. However, if "Grant exclusive rights" is checked, this operation will REMOVE everyone except SYSTEM and the user. This is exactly the problem we are trying to overcome

Comment: The GP I recall modifies this mechanism so that when the client adjusts the folder permissions, it leaves Administrators in as well. That's the GP I'm after...